# Adding a horizontal line to d3 graph displays at the wrong value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg, d3.js

I am trying to add a horizontal line to my graph, relative to the y-axis values, the problem is that they show up at the wrong positions.

The 2 lines should display at values 90 and 140 relative to the y-axis values.

The code I used to add the line is below:

```
if (before_meal !== null || after_meal !== null) {
                    svg.append("svg:line")
                        .attr("x1", 0)
                        .attr("x2", width)
                        .attr("y1", before_meal)
                        .attr("y2", before_meal)
                        .style("stroke", "rgb(189, 189, 189)");

                    svg.append("svg:line")
                        .attr("x1", 0)
                        .attr("x2", width)
                        .attr("y1", after_meal)
                        .attr("y2", after_meal)
                        .style("stroke", "rgb(189, 189, 189)");
}
```

Please see my working example here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/waleedasif322/6g07fbfL/)

Comment: feel free to change the css to colors you like.be creative

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your code you have this:

```
var y = d3.scale.linear()
       .range([height, 0]);
```

This is returning a function `y` which maps pixel space to your plot coordinate space.

So when you do:

```
.attr("y1", before_meal)
```

You are telling d3 to put a line at 90 "pixels".  Instead use:

```
.attr("y1", y(before_meal))
```

Which tells d3 to convert 90 y axis units to the appropriate pixels.

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6g07fbfL/1/).

Comment: I used the scale function but it doesn't still work for me - could you help me here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40620576/draw-horizontal-lines-for-bars-in-nvd3-multi-bar-chart