# draw horizontal lines for bars in nvd3 multi bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart, nvd3.js

I want to draw 2 horizontal lines for each of the bars in this nvd3 multibar chart

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dm89/h9xjo8yh/1/)

I have few queries

1. Why is `yValueScale(0)` not starting from `0` of the plot
2. How do I start drawing the lines from where the bar starts? The `xValueScale("A")` does not start from the start of the bar of `A`
3. How do I get to know the width of the bar to draw the line of length equal to the bar width

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are appending the line to the wrong "container".  The `svg` variable is the entire svg container, `nvd3`'s drawing container, though, is the `g` element:

```
<g class="nvd3 nv-wrap nv-multibar" transform="translate(0,0)">
```

So, use:

```
var g = d3.select("#chart1 svg .nvd3");
g.append("line")
  .style("stroke", "#FF7F0E")
  .style("stroke-width", "2.5px")
  .attr("x1", xValueScale("A"))
  .attr("y1", yValueScale(yValue))
  .attr("x2", xValueScale("A") + 100)
  .attr("y2", yValueScale(yValue));
```

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h9xjo8yh/2/).

Comment: Thanks! Can you also help me in obtaining the width of the bar dynamically?

Comment: @Dinesh, assuming all bars are the same width, it's simply: `d3.select("#chart1 .nv-bar").attr("width")`

Comment: do you have some tutorial for this . (dot) notation - I am not so clear how it is working in the d3.select()

Comment: @Dinesh, it's a CSS selection.  `.` means class name, `#` means by id.  In the above it's find the element with id of "chart1" and then find it's child with a class of "nv-bar".  As always the [mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors) are excellent.

Comment: Thanks, I tried again with the nvd3 discrete bar chart but not able to quite get the exact container in which the drawing is made - https://jsfiddle.net/dm89/qd36csux/3/